# Print Array of Objects in BlueJ

Tags: java, arrays, bluej

For an assignment, I was asked to work on calling a class and creating an array objects, which i did here;

```
public void DVDArrayObjects() {
    //creates variables
    int i;
    DVDClass[] dvdArray = new DVDClass[5];

    //reference to DVDClass
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
        //create new instance of calling the class
            dvdArray[i] = new DVDClass();

        //create new instance of getting the info
            dvdArray[i].getDVDInfo();

        //display
        //System.out.println(dvdArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Creating the array of objects works fine, but displaying doesn't. it shows the memory allocation when i run it. I'm really stuck as to how to get it to display.

** EDIT **

When i use `System.out.println(dvdArray[i].getDVDInfo());` the error `void types not allowed in here` shows up

** END OF EDIT **

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your error is because the `getDVDInfo()` doesn't return anything, it's `void`

Comment: Can't print "nothing"(void). You need your `getDVDInfo()` to `return` something.

Comment: Best bet is to override the toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print the DVD info (assuming that it returns a string).

```
System.out.println(dvdArray[i].getDVDInfo());
```

If it doesn't return a string, you need to override the `toString()` method on the class `DVDInfo` like this.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Film Name\t: " + filmName +
           "\nFilm Director\t: " + filmDirector +
           "\nRun Time\t: " + runTime +
           "\nLead Actor\t: " + leadActor;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: getDVDInfo has one integer value in it as well. it calls filmName, filmDirector, runTime, leadActor

Comment: @MeganSime Changed to include the example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `toString()` method.

```
public class DVDCLass {

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return // whatever you want the output to be
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() method in your DVDClass class

do like below

```
class DVDClass{

     public String toString(){
          return // whatever you want the output to be
     }
}
```